# Should I group different servers into the same New Relic Application?

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform

I have an `Application` which require multiple Java servers, e.g. Tomcat & Solr. As they are also JVM based and used by a single web apps, so should I group them as a single  `Application`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some assumptions here, but if all the components here are part of the same web application, then using the same New Relic application name should be the right way to go.

(background: the 'application name' is used by New Relic to separate performance information out into a single heading. It generally makes sense to use separate application names only if you're using two separate web apps or you have a prod and dev version of an app)

If you'd like to see information for just a single JVM later, the New Relic user interface allows you to view performance information separated out for a single JVM using the drop-down at the top right under an application's name.

Comment: as I mentioned in the question, it is `tomcat` & `solr`. they powered the same application, but they have different work load & characteristics, I am thinking are there any pros/cons when using the same Application Name..

Comment: Generally a single app name will provide a better experience, because it should be quite easy to differentiate within that single heading but still get an overview. You could also use app name roll-up to have everything report to both an 'overall' app name and then a unique name separately. Let me know (maybe a new question?) if you want to pursue this.