# How to group different services under the New Relic App Map

Tags: newrelic

At my company, we deployed our apps with the new relic plugin reporting to their own apps for each of our services (Tomcat, Cassandra, Elastic Search) and reporting to a main app.

We were expecting this behaviour: http://newrelic.com/application-monitoring/app-map , but unfortunately, we all three just got bundled into a single service, which doesn't really helps as we do expect different processing times for each of them.

I've seen the question at
[Should I group different servers into the same New Relic Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585959/should-i-group-different-servers-into-the-same-new-relic-application)

which is not exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using all of these services for the same application, then you should use the same application name for all of them which would give you the insight you are looking for. Otherwise you may wish to use roll-up naming. In your yml file you can set up to three application names separated by semicolon, like this

**app_name: uniqueName;subGroup;overview**

You can use a maximum of three names, and they MUST be in the order

1. unique name
2. Common name
3. Common name

If you are still having trouble with this you may want to open a support ticket at https://support.newrelic.com

Comment: Thank you. I realised our yaml had the other way around. I'm changing this now and I'll accept the answer if this fixes our issue.